# How to create a dictionary from a list of lists and sort it?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Please tell me how to create a dictionary from the existing list:

```
my_list = [[['id_1', 'A', 10], ['id_1', 'C', 3], ['id_1', 'B', 2]],
          [['id_2', 'E', 4], ['id_2', 'A', 3], ['id_2', 'D', 1]],
          [['id_3', 'B', 3], ['id_3', 'C', 1]],
          [['id_4', 'E', 10], ['id_4', 'A', 5], ['id_4', 'B', 4], ['id_4', 'F', 2]]]
```

I need to get a dictionary like this:

```
dictionary = {'A': [('id_1', 10 ), ('id_4', 5), ('id_2', 3)],
              'B': [('id_4', 4), ('id_3', 3), ('id_1', 2)],
              'C': [('id_1', 3), ('id_3', 1)],
              'D': [('id_2', 1)],
              'E': [('id_4', 10), ('id_2', 4)],
              'F': [('id_4', 2)]
              }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Happy to help; but I’m afraid you’ve forgotten to post the code you’ve written to try and solve the question, or the research you’ve conducted to try and solve this on your own, before asking for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a `defaultdict` and append values from `my_list` then sort.

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [[['id_1', 'A', 10], ['id_1', 'C', 3], ['id_1', 'B', 2]],
          [['id_2', 'E', 4], ['id_2', 'A', 3], ['id_2', 'D', 1]],
          [['id_3', 'B', 3], ['id_3', 'C', 1]],
          [['id_4', 'E', 10],['id_4', 'A', 5],['id_4', 'B', 4], ['id_4', 'F', 2]]]

d = defaultdict(list) 
[d[i[1]].append((i[0],i[2])) for j in my_list for i in j]
dictionary = dict(sorted(d.items()))
```

Comment: I think you wanted `dictionary = dict(sorted(d.items()))`; if you don't convert back to `dict`, `sorted` will leave you with a `list` of two-`tuple`s.

Comment: Yes, you're right I wrote it in print but forgot to add it when I removed print.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```py
my_list = [[['id_1', 'A', 10], ['id_1', 'C', 3], ['id_1', 'B', 2]],
          [['id_2', 'E', 4], ['id_2', 'A', 3], ['id_2', 'D', 1]],
          [['id_3', 'B', 3], ['id_3', 'C', 1]],
          [['id_4', 'E', 10], ['id_4', 'A', 5], ['id_4', 'B', 4], ['id_4', 'F', 2]]]

flattened = [item for sublist in my_list for item in sublist]

my_dict = {}

for _id, ltr, num in flattened:
    if ltr in my_dict: # changed from my_dict.keys()
        my_dict[ltr].append((_id, num))
    else:
        my_dict[ltr] = [(_id, num)]

sorted_dict = dict(sorted(my_dict.items()))

print(sorted_dict)
```

---

If you want to know, this is what `flattened`, `my_dict` and `sorted_dict` look like:

```py
flattened = [
    ['id_1', 'A', 10], ['id_1', 'C', 3], ['id_1', 'B', 2],
    ['id_2', 'E', 4], ['id_2', 'A', 3], ['id_2', 'D', 1],
    ['id_3', 'B', 3], ['id_3', 'C', 1], ['id_4', 'E', 10],
    ['id_4', 'A', 5], ['id_4', 'B', 4], ['id_4', 'F', 2]
]

my_dict = {
    'A': [('id_1', 10), ('id_2', 3), ('id_4', 5)],
    'C': [('id_1', 3), ('id_3', 1)],
    'B': [('id_1', 2), ('id_3', 3), ('id_4', 4)],
    'E': [('id_2', 4), ('id_4', 10)],
    'D': [('id_2', 1)],
    'F': [('id_4', 2)]
}

sorted_dict = {
    'A': [('id_1', 10 ), ('id_4', 5), ('id_2', 3)],
    'B': [('id_4', 4), ('id_3', 3), ('id_1', 2)],
    'C': [('id_1', 3), ('id_3', 1)],
    'D': [('id_2', 1)],
    'E': [('id_4', 10), ('id_2', 4)],
    'F': [('id_4', 2)]
}
```

Comment: Minor note: `if ltr in my_dict.keys():`, in Python 3, is always equivalent to, but slightly slower than, `if ltr in my_dict:` (in Python 2, it's *much* slower, Python 3 is only trivially slower). `dict`s already act like sets of their keys in most contexts. The only reason you ever need to call `.keys()` on a `dict` is to use the `set`-like behaviors (e.g. sub/super set comparisons with `<`/`>`, unions, intersections and differencing with `|`, `&`, `-`/`^`).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use nested loops..

```py
my_dict = {}
for i in my_list:
    for j in i:
        try: 
            my_dict[j[1]] += [(j[0], j[-1])]
        except KeyError: 
            my_dict[j[1]] = [(j[0], j[-1])]
my_dict = dict(sorted(my_dict.items()))
my_dict

----------------------------------------------------
{'A': [('id_1', 10), ('id_2', 3), ('id_4', 5)],
 'B': [('id_1', 2), ('id_3', 3), ('id_4', 4)],
 'C': [('id_1', 3), ('id_3', 1)],
 'D': [('id_2', 1)],
 'E': [('id_2', 4), ('id_4', 10)],
 'F': [('id_4', 2)]}
----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: AGH! BARE `except:`!?! WHY MUST YOU TORTURE ME SO?!? (Please make it `except KeyError:`, and ideally put the code for each on separate lines; I know people like it concise, but PEP8 style makes things more readable). Other suggestions: Unpack to names in the for loop, e.g. `for ID, key, val in i:` instead of indexing to `0`, `1` and `-1`, maybe note existence of `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I have adjusted it for you xD

Comment: @ko3 note that OP wants a sorted dictionary

Comment: @TheThonnu, you are absolutely right, corrected that.